# I wish this worked... =if(C16>"0",((B16*E16)-40),D16=B16)

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Theoretical code, I suppose. Been dreaming about really getting into Google Sheets lately and finally decided to ask my mother about it. 20 minutes into Google sheets and I had already written more advanced calculations than she ever had in 20 years.

```
=if(C16>"0",((B16*E16)-40),D16=B16)
```

I'm *frustrated*. I want to create an if statement which poses the question 
(comparing various jobs to be filled out like a questionnaire, filling in from B, then continue right, C, D,~) 
whether C16 is greater than 0. If not, then D16 should be equal to B16. I want to write this formula in a separate cell, to allow the questionnaire to still be filled out. If I slap this formula in D16, then it makes everything messy.

I tried offset, but that still display the answer **within** the cell i wrote the formula in.

Let's put it this way. The cell I want the formula to be in is the command centre, and I want it to reflect/direct number at one cell and show them in another.

Comment: The bit with C16 should be C16>0 ... and then it should be fine.

Comment: So you want this formula in, for example, cell A1, but the result of the formula to be a change in the value of cell D16?

Answer (score 2):

You have a number of issues.

I'm afraid your *"20 minutes of learning"* doesn't have you as "advanced" as you've convinced yourself and you might owe Mum an apology.  :-)

---

### Formulas do *not* change other cells

A formula returns it's result in the cell in which is is placed. Period.  Offset does not move the result; it offsets the a cell that the formula is *referencing*.

---

### `"`Double quotation marks`"` are a text qualifier

Quotation marks are a text qualifier meaning **anything enclosed by double quotes is treated as text**.  This causes a problem for you because you need the `0` to be a number so you can compare it to other numbers (assuming `C16` contains a number).

---

### `D16=B16` is a comparison

This is like saying "Does the value in cell `B16` match the value in cell `D16'?" and returns either`TRUE`or`FALSE`.  Nothing else.

---

Also please review the posting policies for this site.

Comment: Actually my mum said that. Quote: "Wow, you've done more advanced stuff with sheets than I have in 20 years!"

Comment: Is there a possibility to affect other cells? It seems kind of silly that it's not possible.

Comment: @fayella Yes, it's possible. You will likely need to write a custom app script to achieve your desired results...but this should be trivial for a genius of your caliber. See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions for reference.